# C#, how do I use WebAPI to create variables within a class, which can then be referenced in a different class?

Tags: c#, class, asp.net-web-api, streamreader, using

I am updating a Windows Form App which converts different currencies into each other (e.g. Pounds to Euros and vice-versa). One idea I've had is to create a class which utilises a Web API framework in order to:

- **download the latest exchange rates upon starting the program**
- **create variables which individually contain these rates**
- **store these variables privately within the class and reference the relevant variables in each form**

(Unfortunately the assignment REQUIRES a multiform layout - otherwise I would have used drop-down menus in a single form.)

This is the code which I have utilised thus far - in a Console App for the purposes of planning and testing:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string URL = "https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=4837847d2bc64fc496cf325525c5cf0d";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes("GBP"));
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string streamString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string[] streamArray = Regex.Split(streamString, "\n|: |,\\s*");

            foreach (string s in streamArray)
            {
                if (s.Equals("\"GBP\""))
                {
                    int element = Array.IndexOf(streamArray,s);
                    string dTPString = streamArray[element + 1];
                    double dollarsToPounds = Convert.ToDouble(dTPString);
                }

                if (s.Equals("\"EUR\""))
                {
                    int element = Array.IndexOf(streamArray, s);
                    string dTEString = streamArray[element + 1];
                    double dollarsToEuros = Convert.ToDouble(dTEString);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(dollarsToPounds); //does not work
        Console.WriteLine(dollarsToEuros); //does not work
    }
```

Having tested the array assignments and both double variables "dollarsToPounds" and "dollarsToEuros" have been proven to possess their correct values *within the context of the "using (Stream...)" statement* - however, due to the properties of "using", **these variables have not been assigned values outside of its context** (declaring the variables at the start of Main() does not affect this outcome).

Is there a method structure I could use instead which would perform the same task as "using (Stream...)" i.e. to read the contents of the provided URL, which would then allow for the variables to be referenced elsewhere within the same class? This would then allow me to reference it outside of the class.

If you need me to explain the code further then by all means ask.

Comment: You can move the declarations of  double dollarsToPounds  and  double dollarsToEuros  to before the line static void Main(string[] args)

Comment: Thank you very much! I played around with this and it seems to have done the trick! I appreciate your help. Gonna edit my initial question to show my implementation of this advice.

Comment: Tip: If you are writing your Web API to the Cloud, give a look at Azure Functions. It is very interesting.

Comment: I will post this as answer so you can edit and mark it as answer.

Comment: Done! Thank you again, especially for being so prompt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the declarations of

```
double dollarsToPounds
```

and

```
double dollarsToEuros
```

to before the line

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Tony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194717/tony)'s advice, I have implemented a solution to the above question I asked!
The key is to declare the variables dollarsToPounds and dollarsToEuros BEFORE you enter the method where the WebAPI and StreamReader are implemented, and to call an instance of the class at the start of the method before doing so:

```
 class Program
{
    double dollarsToPounds;
    double dollarsToEuros;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();

        string URL = "https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=4837847d2bc64fc496cf325525c5cf0d";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes("GBP"));
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string streamString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string[] streamArray = Regex.Split(streamString, "\n|: |,\\s*");

            foreach (string s in streamArray)
            {
                if (s.Equals("\"GBP\""))
                {
                    int element = Array.IndexOf(streamArray,s);
                    string dTPString = streamArray[element + 1];

                    program.dollarsToPounds = Convert.ToDouble(dTPString);
                }

                if (s.Equals("\"EUR\""))
                {
                    int element = Array.IndexOf(streamArray, s);
                    string dTEString = streamArray[element + 1];
                    program.dollarsToEuros = Convert.ToDouble(dTEString);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(program.dollarsToPounds); //works!
        Console.WriteLine(program.dollarsToEuros); //works!
    }
}
```

The structure, simplified:

```
class ClassName
{
    //variables go here

    static void MethodName()
    {
        ClassName instance = new ClassName();
            //Web API, using StreamReader, arrays, nested foreach-if statements go here
        //variables can now be referenced outside of "using" context
    }
}
```

Thank you once again! My lecturer is probably going to feel a bit silly when I show him this tomorrow.